# how to fix Image set in position absolute overlap screen and create space on right side?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

I have an Image that is supposed to be half hidden on media query mobile screen. it is set as position: absolute and left: 50% so the half side is hidden in the screen, but when I do this, it creates a space at the right side, creating an overflow, which is not good for the appearance. can this be fixed? or is there a right way implementing it? I've seen other sites have this kind of sections but the scroll the whitespace on the right doesn't appear? or is the overflow hidden for the body just disabled?

I've provided a visual on the problem, hope you can help me with this. still learning CSS.

the black one is the screen, purple one is the new width and the red one is the image. thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
html
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It will force the site to be 100% of the available space and hide any horizontal scrolling.